# PMD violations missing in problems view

Tags: eclipse, pmd

With Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 and PMD plug-in 4.0.3, PMD violations are shown in its own violations outline, its violations overview and in the editor, but not in the standard problems view. That view is configured to "show all". "Configure contents" reveals that in the types list, only "PMD DFA Marker" is selectable, but not "PMD Marker", "PMD Problems" or something similar. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin. Any ideas?

Note that in the following screenshot, I did not use "show all", but a demo configuration as requested in a comment to this question.
[image]

Comment: The fact that only "PMD DFA Marker" appears is normal.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the "Configure Contents" dialog? Then we could compare to ours. Make sure that "match *any* configuration" is selected and not "match *all* configurations".

Comment: OK, I have reproduced your problem. No clue why this is happening though. Must be a bug :-( Personally, I work only with global rulesets and PMD builders enabled. This seems to somehow avoid the problem. Maybe it happens if you run the PMD analysis before enabling PMD for the project. Sorry I can't help you further.